# Intersecting diameter and chord

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations, triangles, circles

> A diameter $AB$ and a chord $CD$ of a circle $k$ intersect at $M.$ $CE$ and $DF$ are perpendiculars from $C$ and $D$ to $AB$. $(A,E,M,F,B$ lie on AB in that order$)$. What is the length of $CD$ if $AE=1,FB=49$ and $MC:MD=2:7$?

[image]
How do I approach the given problem? I would be very grateful if you could give me some hints and tips to follow. I see that the triangles $CEM$ and $DFM$ are similar and $\dfrac{MC}{MD}=\dfrac{CE}{DF}=\dfrac{EM}{FM}=\dfrac{2}{7}.$

Comment: Is it possible to thrice increase label font sizes for readability? Thanks.

Comment: @Narasimham, is it now readable?

Comment: Yes, thanks about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $CM=2x$ and $EM=2y$.

Thus, $$MF=7y,$$ $$MD=7x$$ and since $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}$, we obtain $$CE^2=AE\cdot EB.$$
Also, $$AM\cdot MB=CM\cdot MD$$ and we obtain the following system:
$$(2x)^2-(2y)^2=1\cdot(2y+7y+49)$$ and $$(1+2y)(7y+49)=2x\cdot7x.$$
The last equality it's $$(1+2y)(y+7)=2x^2$$ and we can substitute $2x^2$ in the first equation.

Thus $$2(1+2y)(y+7)-4y^2=9y+49.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $CD=39$.

Comment: @LYI It's given that $AB$ is a diameter

Comment: It was typo. I fixed.

Comment: Can I also ask you how did you get the first equation? What is it?

Comment: I am talking about $(2x)^2-(2y)^2=1\cdot(2y+7y+49)$.

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you! I see it now. Any tips on solving the system?

Comment: @LYI I almost solved already. See please better my post.

Comment: I've already seen it. But I want to solve the system myself. How did you approach it?

Comment: @LYI From the last equation we obtain $y=\frac{5}{3}$ and after this $x=\frac{13}{3}.$

Comment: Thank you! But how can I get $2(1+2y)(y+7)-4y^2=9y+49$?

Comment: @LYI I added something again.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: @LYI Good luck!